# Why is app in Pinax project not appearing?

Tags: python, django, social-networking, pinax

I'm getting:

```
ImportError at /
No module named tribes.models
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://stornge.com:8000/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named tribes.models
Exception Location: /home/jonathan/clay/apps/tribes/admin.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /home/jonathan/virtual_environment/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/jonathan/clay/apps',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax/apps',
 '/home/jonathan/clay',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Mon, 25 Mar 2013 14:57:41 -0400
```

It's not finding tribes. But the tribes app appears in the first entry on the Python path:

```
(virtual_environment)jonathan@li393-189:~/clay/apps/tribes$ ls -l
total 68
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan  215 Mar 25 15:05 admin.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan  580 Mar 25 18:55 admin.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonathan jonathan 4096 Mar 25 15:05 fixtures
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan 1561 Mar 25 15:05 forms.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 jonathan jonathan    0 Mar 25 15:05 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan  130 Mar 25 15:05 __init__.pyc
drwxrwxr-x 11 jonathan jonathan 4096 Mar 25 15:05 locale
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan  904 Mar 25 15:05 management.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan 1221 Mar 25 17:14 management.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  3 jonathan jonathan 4096 Mar 25 15:05 media
-rwxrwxr-x  1 jonathan jonathan  539 Mar 25 15:05 models.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan 1177 Mar 25 15:05 models.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  3 jonathan jonathan 4096 Mar 25 15:05 templates
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonathan jonathan 4096 Mar 25 15:05 templatetags
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonathan jonathan 4096 Mar 25 15:05 tests
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonathan jonathan  865 Mar 25 15:05 urls.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 jonathan jonathan 5693 Mar 25 15:05 views.py
(virtual_environment)jonathan@li393-189:~/clay/apps/tribes$
```

How can I get apps/tribes to be recognized as providing tribes.models?

Comment: what if `from models import foo` instead of `from tribes.models import foo` in `admin.py`?

Comment: Breadcrumb remark: I made this post as part of a concerted effort to get a Pinax 0.7.3 social project to work with a more recent version of Pinax (for reasons beyond me, the social project in Pinax 1.0.0 is a bare stub, complete with lorem ipsum in the final page). It took me a lot of digging to get to Pinax 0.7.3 (there are innumerable places advertising a free Pinax 0.7.3 download, but I tried dozens and they all pointed to a pinaxproject.com (now) 404. Having found Pinax 0.7.3 and wanting to save other programmers the headache, I have made it available at http://JonathansCorner.com/pinax